# Numbers cube, each row rotated to left by one

Tags: c#

Basic C# question:
I need to have that result when entering some number (this case was entered 4):

```
4 3 2 1 0
3 2 1 0 4
2 1 0 4 3
1 0 4 3 2
```

I was trying that code, but cant figure out my mistake:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please write a Number: ");
Console.Write("Number: ");
int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
{
    for (int j = num - i; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        Console.Write(j);
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(j);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

This is the output I get:

```
4 3 2 1 0
3 2 1 0 1
2 1 0 1 2
1 0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: if you look at each row, then it is *shifted* to the left.. easy peasy! That means you need 1 cycle and 1 subcycle (not 2), but make a shift in the subcycle.

Comment: This looks like homework.  Are there any constraints on the solution (ie: have you been asked to solve this using a particular method? Do you need to use loops, for example?)

Comment: Debug it and see if it works like you want it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please write a Number: ");
Console.Write("Number: ");
int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
{
    for (int j = num - i; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        Console.Write(j);
    }
    for (int j = num; j > num - i; j--)
    {
        Console.Write(j);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: +1 Perfect . but it is printing extra row 04321, otherwise everything is fine. i think i<=num must be i<num.

Comment: I think this shouldn't be a problem for him :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your second inner loop is starting at one and counting up rather than starting from `num` and counting down.

Change that loop to:

```
for (int j = num; j > num -i; j--)
{
    Console.Write(j);
}
```

Also I'm not clear if you want the last line of 04321 or not. If you don't (as in the original example) then just change your loop check to `i<num`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

1. get a number(x) from user.
2. create a list of integer containing x to 0.
3. run a loop for x times.
4. every time print the list and pop the first number and push it at the end

> ```
> var ints = new List<int> { 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
> for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
> {
>     ints.ForEach(n => Console.Write(n + " "));
>     Console.WriteLine("");
>     var a = ints[0];
>     ints.RemoveAt(0);
>     ints.Add(a);
> }
> ```

Comment: This may not win prizes for efficiency but I really like it for how clearly and intuitively it is doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint I give you the main loop as a pseudo code:

```
for i from 0 to number_input-1 {
    for j from number_input to 0 {
        print((j-i)%(number_input+1) + " ")
    }
    print("\n")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
const int NUM = 4; // num from user
for (int start = NUM; start > 0; start--)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= NUM; i++)
    {
        int current = (start - i) >= 0 ? start - i : NUM + (start - i) + 1;
        Console.Write(current + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this is a classic sorting task. it's just hidden beyond "user types and bla bla bla" but I remember at school it was..
There is an array [4,3,2,1,0].. so

1. we swap 1 and 2 and get [3,4,2,1,0].
2. we swap 2 and 3 and get [3,2,4,1,0].
3. we swap 3 and 4 and get [3,2,1,4,0].
4. we swap 4 and 5 and get [3,2,1,0,4].

so just simple code

`int[] numbers` let say you have this array [4,3,2,1,0]

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 2; i++){
    for(int y = 0; y < numbers.length - 1; y++){
        int buf = numbers[y];
        numbers[y] = numbers[y + 1];
        numbers[y + 1] = buf;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really clear on what your answer is attempting to do. One thing I can be pretty confident of is that it is not printing out anything which the question requires. Also I don't see how sorting comes into it anywhere...